# Change parameters within methodeheaders

Tags: java

I found some old code within a old Project. I don't understand how it works.
Lets take a look.

```
public class Test{

int someNumber = 1337;

public void someMethode(){
    calledMethode(someNumber, someNumber=42);
  }

public void calledMethode(int _oldValue, int _newValue) {
    System.out.println("Show _oldValue: "+_oldValue);
    System.out.println("Show _newValue: "+_newValue);
  }
}
```

I expected the result being:

```
Show _oldValue: 42
Show _newValue: 42
```

In fact i got the following result:

```
Show _oldValue: 1337
Show _newValue: 42
```

Why is this happening? Thanks for your help and have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is expected, the reason being subexpressions are evaluated left to right.

```
class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "going, ";
        print3(s, s, s = "gone");
    }
    static void print3(String a, String b, String c) {
        System.out.println(a + b + c);
    }
}
```

Gives result : going, going, gone

Refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.4

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is correct. Have a look at bytecode of `someMethode()` below.`someNumber` value is first loaded in a stack followed by that new value is pushed. When we call the method JVM will load the oldValue and new value from the stack.

```
  public void someMethode();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: aload_0
       2: getfield      #7                  // Field someNumber:I
       5: aload_0
       6: bipush        42
       8: dup_x1
       9: putfield      #7                  // Field someNumber:I
      12: invokevirtual #13                 // Method calledMethode:(II)V
      15: return
```

Read 
[JVM Byte code instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings) 
[Invoke Dynamic](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2860079/invokedynamic-101.html)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.4

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

```
public class Test{

int someNumber = 1337;

public void someMethode(){
    calledMethode(someNumber, someNumber=42);
  }

public void calledMethode(int _oldValue, int _newValue) {
    System.out.println("Show _oldValue: "+_oldValue);
    System.out.println("Show _newValue: "+_newValue);
  }
}
```

in the method - someMethode, you are passing through two parameters, your first parameter is someNumber which as you declared at the beginning of your class, contains 1337. So 1337 will be passed through but in the second parameter you have reassigned the variable someNumber with a new value of 42, so 42 will be passed through.

If you want the output to be 42, 42 then your code should look as follows:

```
public class Test{

int someNumber = 42;

public void someMethode(){
    calledMethode(someNumber, someNumber);
  }

public void calledMethode(int _oldValue, int _newValue) {
    System.out.println("Show _oldValue: "+_oldValue);
    System.out.println("Show _newValue: "+_newValue);
  }
}
```